# Exact search from search box in NetSuite

Tags: oracle-netsuite

I'm trying to use hash tags in the subject of NetSuite case to organize support cases, so I can search for specific tags.

When I use the global search box to find `#process/form` I get lots of results, but I only tagged a couple of cases with this in the subject.

I tried searching `"#process/form"` but I get a similar large set.

Is there an **easy** way to do a simple exact search using the global search box at the top of the page?